# How to capture kendo grid hide/show when column checkbox is clicked

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo grid. One of the requirements is that the data of the hidden columns will be fetched only when the column becomes visible.
I want to use default column seletion (in the column menu), so when the checkbox of column is checked I want to catch it and go to the server to get relevant data and show the column only after the data arrives (or maybe even to rebuild the grid, whatever is possible). I can't find how to catch this click event and prevent default behavior?

Comment: when you say "hidden columns will be fetched only when the column becomes visible", do you mean that you **don't** want that data coming from the server until you display the column?

Comment: Exactly, I want to get the data from the server only when the column becomes visible. Actually, the user selects the column and before showing the column I want to get the data and only then to show the column.